# Curl error protocol not supported

Tags: curl, cmd

[image: curl error]

I am trying to delete components from nexus repository created component for delete by generating REST API

```
curl -X DELETE --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:8081/service/siesta/rest/beta/components/sam'
```

I get these errors:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
curl: (1) Protocol "'http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate did I am using any wrong version here

Comment: Try double quoting the URL on the windows command line.  It does not support single quotes for enclosing strings like that.

Comment: Thanks Drew for your reply as you told added double quotes to the url
curl -X DELETE --header 'Accept: application/json' "http://localhost:8081/service/siesta/rest/beta/components/sam"

now i getting these error any idea

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application

Comment: Also use double quotes for the `Accept: application/json` part.

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes (') are not supported by the Windows cmd command prompt. You must use double quotes (") instead with that shell.

The single quotes you use will not be stripped off by the shell and are instead passed on to curl that reads them as part of the arguments and that is certainly not what you want.

Your command line should therefore rather be written like this:

```
curl -X DELETE --header "Accept: application/json" "http://localhost:8081/service/siesta/rest/beta/components/sam"
```

Alternatively, use a shell/system that supports single quotes.

Comment: Daniel thanks for your reply is this is correct am I missing any thing here

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to use it with double quotes instead of single quotes.